# Firebase Push in Android doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am having a problem using push in my Android app, the examples I found on Firebase.com seems to show how to use push to create a node, but not a key/value.
I can do this in the console very easly
ref.push(key);
but in Android I can't find a way of doing it other than this one which doesn't work, I am not sure why, is it because of the cascading?

```
Firebase ref1= new Firebase(loc);
ref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.child(info1).exists()){
  Firebase ref2 = new Firebase(loc2);
  Firebase newinfo = ref2.push();
  newinfo.setValue(info2, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
    if (firebaseError != null) {
    } else {
    Toast.makeText(Activity.this,"Done!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }}});}}

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
  }});}
```

My app always show "Done!" but no data is written on Firebase.

Comment: Can you provide the values of `ref1`, `ref2`, `loc`, `loc2`, and `info2`? It's hard to tell what's going on without these details.

Comment: I don't think loc's and ref's matter in this question, it is about the technique of how to write a key/value using push in Android, you could provide your own loc's and ref's. Anyway, I managed to solve the problem and posted the solution, if you have better one please post as well, thank you.

Comment: It's important to provide as much information as possible. We aren't privy to your use case so every bit of detail helps. Especially when you're stuck and don't know exactly is needed to solve the problem.

Comment: I agree, I just though it might cause more confusion and time wasting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue

```
Firebase ref2 = new Firebase(loc2);
Firebase ref3 = ref2.push();
Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<String, Object>();
info.put(ref3.getKey(), info2);
ref2.updateChildren(info, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
  if (firebaseError != null) {
  } else {
     Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}});}}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
}});}
```